# What does this Ruby code inside initialize do?

Tags: ruby, initialization

I'm trying to figure out what this code is doing, and I have a guess. I'm familiar with assigning arguments to instance variables but I'm not sure about the rest.

How I'm reading `player_1`: If `player_1` is a passed in a value, assign it to instance variable `@player_1`, and create a new instance of the `Human` class. Am I missing something?

```
def initialize(player_1 = nil, player_2 = nil, board = nil)
  player_1 ? @player_1 = player_1 : @player_1 = Players::Human.new("X")
  player_2 ? @player_2 = player_2 : @player_2 = Players::Human.new("O")
  board ? @board = board : @board = Board.new
  @current_player = @player_1
end

module Players
  class Human < Player
    def move(board)
      input = gets.strip
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically assign the `@player_1`, `@player_2` and `@board` instance variables what was passed as arguments with the same name. If something was missing, there is a default value for it. The default values are "human player with `X`", "human player with `O`" and "a new board" respectively. Looks like a Tic-Tac-Toe setup.

---

A way more readable way to write it would be:

```
def initialize(first_player = nil, second_player = nil, board = nil)
  @first_player   = first_player || Players::Human.new("X")
  @second_player  = second_player || Players::Human.new("O")
  @board          = board || Board.new
  @current_player = @first_player
end
```

Comment: Honestly I would prefer `initialize(first_player = Players::Human.new("X"), second_player = Players::Human.new("O"), board = Board.new)` then you can just set the instance variables without condition.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I agree. My thinking was that this prevents you from setting the value for the `second_player`, but keeping the default for `first_player`. Ideally, they should be all kwargs.

Comment: I can agree with the kwargs comment for sure

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, and giving me better way to write it!

Answer (score 2):

All arguments on initialize are optional, and if not set are nil. When you call initialize, it will check for each variable if it is nil. If it's not nil, it will just assign the parameter value to the instance variable, else it will create a Player::Human or Board. Lastly it assigns the current_player to player_1.

Comment: I liked your description a lot, makes sense.